# Size of intersection of two sublists in R

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if this is has already been asked. I could not come up with a descriptive search term.

I have the following list:

```
list(
c('apples', 'bananas', 'pears'),
c('dragons'),
c('strawberries'),
c('apples','bananas','strawberries')
)
```

I am looking for a function `f` that would return the share of elements that have term X also have term Y.

For instance: I know that every time my list element has the term 'bananas', it also has the term 'apples'; i.e. `f('bananas', 'apples') = 1`. Analogously, `f('strawberries','apples') = 0.5` because there are 2 list elements with 'strawberries', but only 1 of them also has 'bananas'. To give one more example, I would expect `f('apples','strawberries')` to return 0.5 as I have 2 elements with 'apples', and one of them also has 'strawberries.'

I realise that I could do this with 2 loops, where in the first pass, I would create  templist1, that has all the elements which contain the first argument of f(), and in the second step I would create templist2 which would contain all the elements of templist1 which contain the second argument of f(). My answer would then simply be `length(templist2)/length(templist1)`. I am looking for a vectorised implementation.

Any pointers welcome. Thanks! :)

Comment: Good question! I would expect f('apples','strawberries') to return 0.5 as I have 2 elements with 'apples', and one of them also has 'strawberries.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
x<-list(
  c('apples', 'bananas', 'pears'),
  c('dragons'),
  c('strawberries'),
  c('apples','bananas','strawberries')
)

get_f <- function(x) {
  function(a, b) {
    hasfirst <- sapply(x, `%in%`, x=a)
    hasfirstandsecond <- sapply(x[hasfirst], `%in%`, x=b)
    sum(hasfirstandsecond)/sum(hasfirst)
  }
}
```

then you can do

```
f <- get_f(x)
f('bananas', 'apples')
# [1] 1
f('strawberries','apples')
# [1] 0.5
f('apples','strawberries')
# [1] 0.5
```

Comment: I like this solution so much that I deleted my own. It is a definite optimization to use the already computed `hasfirst` in `hasfirstandsecond`.